# <ol> are not as expected when the data is exported

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the below css code to show the ordered list in my web page. I have exported the content to the PDF, then the ordered lists in the PDF are showing different as shown in the image link below.

```
 ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol li { display: block }

ol li:before {
content: counter(item) ". ";
counter-increment: item;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Please click here to view the image of the exported ordered list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsQZn.jpg)

Please check for the working demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/zz6ep51k9ZX1THDDZ8Gj?p=preview
When clicked on export button, we can see the data is exported and PDF is generated. In the generated PDF we can notice the ordered list are not shown properly as it should be.Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```css
ol{
  list-style: none;
}
@media print{
  ol{
    list-style: decimal;
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>test1</li>

<li>test1</li>
<li>test1</li>

</ol>
```

Comment: It's not working with the code you suggested. Please find the updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/zz6ep51k9ZX1THDDZ8Gj?p=preview . When clicked on export button, the content is exported to the PDF and you can notice in PDF the <ol> items are not shown as expected..@Michel Simões

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused now.. It has to show numbers 1 2 3 as shown on the webpage as I have <ol> to show numbered options and <ul> to show bullets.  Bullets are shown properly on the exported PDF which you can see in the screenshot you added but the numbered options are not shown. It has to show as 1.option1 2.option2 under TEST.@Michel Simões

Comment: Oh I think it is with the css code I have used content: counter(item) ". " . I don't want to show that text. I want to display numbered options as it was showing on the webpage :(. Any inputs@content: counter(item) ". ";

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html , Please see COLORED LIST NUMBERS topic in that link. I want the numbers to be displayed when <ol> is used in the exported PDF.Sorry for the confusion.@Michel Simões

Comment: do you try on @media print {} your ol list-style: decimal

Comment: I tried @media print but nothing was showing on the exported PDF, but have not tried ol list-style: decimal .

Comment: try export pdf on chrome with print media

Comment: in example, the number are displays on this stackoverflow page

Comment: It is showing blank both on the webpage and in the exported PDF. Please find the updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/zz6ep51k9ZX1THDDZ8Gj?p=preview  . Yiu can notice on the webpage where <ol> is used it is not showing any numbers.

Comment: your PDF library probably don't use CSS3, if you make 'ctrl+p' on example page, you see the numbers...

Comment: I think it does not support CSS3, but it was not supporting the bullets too, then I have included the css code which then I could able to show the bullets in the exported PDF, you can notice it in the demo plunker I shared. If you remove the css hack I gave for <ul> it wont show bullets in the PDF  .myDivClass ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.myDivClass ul li::before {
 content: "\2022";
}. There should be some workaround to show <ol> as I gave for <ul>